# Parallel Tasks not waiting

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

I'm trying to use the .NET 4.0 Task Parallel library, and I'm running into some issues with the Task Wait. Basically, I want to iterate through a list, and create a Task to call a webservice method for each item, execute them in parallel and then wait for all the Tasks to complete.

I have tried the WaitAll as well as the Wait for all tasks one-by-one pattern, and neither seem to work. The webservice might all be triggered in parallel, but then it doesn't seem to wait for the webservice responses, so the Task skip the Wait and complete.

Is there something i am missing here?

```
foreach (Item currentItem in ItemList)
{

 // create task for webservice call.
 Task<Item> itemTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
          Item result = Utilities.UpdateItem(currentItem);
          return result;

        });

        // add to the task list.
        taskList.Add(itemTask);

}

// create task array
Task[] taskArray = taskList.ToArray();
//wait for tasks to complete
Task.WaitAll(taskArray);
```

i have also tried the following, as an alternative to the WaitAll

```
// wait for all tasks, one-by-one pattern
while (taskList.Count > 0)
{
    Task<Item>[] tasks = taskList.ToArray();
    int index = Task.WaitAny(tasks);

    var result = tasks[index].Result;

    taskList.RemoveAt(index);
}
```

The call to the static method `Utilities.UpdateItem`, basically builds a result based on sequential webservice calls which modify the `Item` object and returns it. What I am finding is that all the tasks get queued up, then where I am expecting the Wait to take quite a bit of time for the webservice call, the tasks appear to completes relatively quickly before the calls return.

Comment: using `Parallel.Foreach` would be simpler. I does what you try to achieve.

Comment: "neither seem to work" doesn't tell us what you observe. Please post a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Are you sure your code hasn't already finished due eg. to exceptions that you handle silently? What does the code inside UpdateItem do? Task.WaitAll definitely works, trying to find something wrong with it is a waste of time

Answer (score 0):

I've run your code against my webservice and I cannot reproduce that *"the Task skip the Wait and complete"*

It is waiting for completion in all 3 points of waiting (there were more before edit), have tried individually and in combination:

- `Task.WaitAll(taskArray);`
- `int index = Task.WaitAny(tasks)`;
- `var result = tasks[index].Result;`

Comment: I edited my above post. I wasnt duplicating, i was providing an alternative approach that i was taking, but i did not explain that in my post.